# Generating random but still valid expressions based on yacc/bison/ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, bison, yacc

Is it possible? Any tool available for this?

Comment: did't get your question ,are you asking for this http://flex.sourceforge.net/ if not then please elaborate

Comment: No, not about flex. You know, yacc/bison/ANTLR parses *expressions* using specific *grammar*. I need to generate random *expressions* valid for specified *grammar*. For example, using calculator grammar, I would like to have a tool to produce expressions like "1+2+3", "1+4*8", etc, infinitely and randomly.

Comment: @nav-jan: why should this be easy?  Assertions without backup are really not helpful.  (Well, a numeric calculator langauge might be easy).

Comment: Haskell's [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) might be of aid in this. You could possibly write a grammar for [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/index.html) (like yacc for Haskell), and then use QuickCheck to generate random trees. Admittedly you could skip Happy and just use QC to generate random ASTs for a given data definition. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: Purpose? Testing, of course! :)

Comment: I've looked for this as well and didn't find anything. This would be much more useful if it could read an EBNF and generate input from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yacc and bison turn your grammar into a finite state machine.  You should be able to traverse the state machine randomly to find valid inputs.

Basically, at each state you can either shift a new token on to the stack and move to a new state or reduce the top token in the stack based on a set of valid reductions. (See the [Bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Understanding) for details about how this works).

Your random generator will traverse the state machine making random but valid shifts or reductions at each state. Once you reach the terminal state you have a valid input.

For a human readable description of the states you can use the `-v` or `--report=state` option to bison.

I'm afraid I can't point you to any existing tools that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with any system that gives you access to base grammar.  ANTLR and YACC compile your grammar away so you don't have them anymore.  In ANTLR's case, the grammar has been turned into code; you're not going to get it back.  In YACC's case, you end up with parser tables, which contain the essence of the grammar; you could walk such parse tables if you understood them well enough to do what I describe below as.

It is easy enough to traverse a set of explicitly represented grammar rules and randomly choose expansions/derivations.  By definition this will get you valid syntax.

What it won't do is get you valid *code*.  The problem here is that most languages really have context sensitive syntax;  most programs aren't valid unless the declared identifiers are used in a way consistent with their declaration and scoping rules.    That latter requires a full semantic check.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is used to parse code in arbitrary languages [using a grammar], build ASTs, lets you analyze and transform those trees, and finally prettyprint valid (syntactic) text.  DMS provides direct access to the grammar rules, and tree building facilities, so it is pretty easy to generate random syntactic trees (and prettyprint).  Making sure they are semantically valid is hard with DMS too; however, many of DMS's front ends can take a (random) tree and do semantic checking, so at least you'd know if the tree was semantically valid.

What you do if it says "no" is still an issue.  Perhaps you can generate identifier names in way that guarantees at least not-inconsistent usage, but I suspect that would be langauge-dependent.

Comment: Yes, names is a next question... I need to generate random ASTs so far as a first step.